# File picker and Image picker not working due to plugins not automatically attaching to FragmentActivity

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, filepicker

I have added flutter in an existing Android app and I have been facing issues with File picker library not working.

After some debugging I believe it's due to GeneratedPluginRegistrant not being registered.

I Believe using a FlutterFragmentActivity is not mandatory with a FlutterFragment
Please correct me if I am wrong, as mentioned in this doc [document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-fragment).

Now without FlutterFragmentActivity I can't override `configureFlutterEngine` method and can't register Plugins manually using below code.
`GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)`

I have looked through everywhere but haven't found a way to register plugins without using FlutterFragmentActivity.